# How to run ng serve with PathLocationStrategy while falling back to index.html when page is refreshed

Tags: angular, angular-routing, webpack-dev-server

For some reasons (e.g Hiding the # from the user), we would like to use PathLocationStrategy as the routing strategy for our Angular 8 Application.

We are about to fallback to index.html while deploying the application to an Nginx server. But the problem we are facing is, when we run ng serve locally, the application won't bootstrap when page is refreshed.

I have tried to use a [custom webpack config](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-webpack-config/) to enable devServer.historyApiFallback, it doesn't work.

I have also read through quite a few docs like [this](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples), but no luck

Is there any workaround to spin up a local server that supports the PathLocationStrategy better? Thanks!

Comment: By default, `ng serve` supports this. You shouldn't encounter this problem while running locally. On the other hand, you would have to make some config on your prod server to support this

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner not so sure why, but it doesn't work locally, it only work for prod server (config updated). Any more background information would help? The application is running on Angular 8.

Comment: Just go back to the original state. When you create an angular application using angular cli, it works as you expect. You might have added some config which could be messing this up.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, it turned out to be a "<base href>" that pointed to a path different than "/" when using "ng serve". Changing it to '<base href="/">' solve it for us.